# Auto Compleate codeigniter Not Working On Server

Tags: codeigniter

This is My code Actually Working IN my Local Server But When i Upload Online Its Not Working

My View Page

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" onkeypress="getmedicien(0)"  id="medicine_name0"  name="medicine_name0">

function getmedicien(n){   
          $("#medicine_name"+n).autocomplete({
               source: "<?php echo site_url('doctor_prescription/get_mediciens'); ?>",
               select: function(event,ui){
                event.preventDefault(); 
                 $("#medicine_name"+n).val(ui.item.value);
                 $("#medicine_id"+n).val(ui.item.id); 
                }
          }); 
    }
```

This My Controller code

```
public function get_mediciens(){
          $term = $this->input->post('term'); 
            $this->db->distinct();
            $this->db->select("id,name");
            $this->db->from('medicine');
            $this->db->like('name', $term);
            $this->db->group_by('medicine.name');
            $this->db->limit(10);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $mediData = array();
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                 $data['id']    = $row['id'];
                $data['value']  = $row['name']; 
               array_push($mediData, $data);
            }
            echo json_encode($mediData);  
    }
```

Comment: are you getting any console or network errors when doing this in your production server? (btw, I wouldn't call the controller from  `getmedicien(0)` on every keypress. A fast typer could easily generate 10 requests to your backend in less than a second, which under production load could be a lot to handle. I'd wait until the field has at least 3-4 characters entered before querying the controller)

Comment: No got Error Number: 1055</p><p>Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Comment: Ok, the problem is your query. Most likely your production database is configured to enforce strict grouping rules. The error you're getting means that you are using `group by`, but the first field in your `select` statement is not being used to group (this is one of several rules the strict mode enforces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting `Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column(...)` it means your production database is in strict mode (which is a good thing), making it a little bit less flexible in terms of what it considers valid.

One of many rules being enforced is that when using `group by`, the first element in your `select` statement must be one of the elements you are grouping by.

try changing `$this->db->group_by('medicine.name');` for `$this->db->group_by('id');` and you should be OK

Comment: @ javier Larroulet Thank You its working now But The result is not shown in auto complete

Comment: are you getting any console errors in your browser as you type in the form?